# Unable to obtain html content from a given url using method downloadstring(), how to resolve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webclient, downloadstring

I am trying to read the html content from a given url , this is my simple c# code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();    
var downloadString = client.DownloadString("https://www.yahoo.com"); // suppose
```

but the problem is I cannot obtain the html content, after executing the code it tells in my IDE: "before you can move on please  activate javascript" , but javascript is enabled in all my browers (firefox/explorer/chrome  )

how to resolve this?

Comment: Couldn't this be because https? Is this work ok on any regular page? Also there is some strange domain name, check it out.

Comment: the domain name is edited now, i mistyped it here in stackoverflow, still the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you misspelled the domain name. In other way it works just fine. http://screencast.com/t/3YibceMtSFu

Comment: "https://www.manta.com/c/mmsr0vz/water-district" can you check with this url, i still cannot obtain the html content in the string

Comment: With this Url it also works fine: http://screencast.com/t/T2diaXG0wz
 There may be some environment configuration involved because in my sample it's just console application. Try another approach with HttpWebRequest maybe this could help or point to a problem: http://screencast.com/t/JBcF1Wcm8xx

Comment: thanks , i think the problem is related to cache, it still doesnt work for me i am figuring out :(